# Is there any action to take for questions closed as unclear but already has answers?

Tags: discussion, unclear

Sometimes I would find questions closed as unclear but may potentially deduce what it is asking by the answers like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693141).

The problem I raised is: if a question has answers, is that mean it is not unclear and hence contradict with closed reason "unclear"?

Is there any action need to take for such type of questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often, those answers are just guessing; they're arbitrarily filling in some further information from a superficially similar experience they had, or picking a random interpretation of some seriously unclear wording, in order to come up with an answer that might or might not have anything to do with the asker's question. This is, of course, rather less likely to be useful to the asker.

But worse, it isn't as useful to anyone else. A good *question* is one that clearly explains **to others who would like to ask the same question** exactly what the issue is, so they can immediately tell whether or not this question is relevant **before** reading the answers. An answerer who cheats and stuffs unexplained conditions into the answer is short-circuiting this and harming the mission of the site by making the Internet worse.

Make the question work, then make the answers work.